# SQL syntax error near GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to create a custom way of displaying posts from a wordpress site. Having issues getting the exact data I need from the database.

So this is my error:

```
Error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY Imgguid' at line 24
```

And this is my query:

```
$sql="SELECT  Posts.post_title AS Title, ImgURL.guid AS Imgguid, Posts.guid, Posts.post_content
FROM `wp_posts` AS Posts
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS Meta ON Posts.ID = Meta.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS Featured ON Posts.ID = Featured.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS StartF ON Posts.ID = StartF.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS EndF ON Posts.ID = EndF.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS ImgID ON Posts.ID = ImgID.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_posts` AS ImgURL ON ImgID.meta_value = ImgURL.ID
WHERE
  (Featured.meta_key = '_ecp_custom_22' AND Featured.meta_value = 'yes')
  AND
  (StartF.meta_key = '_ecp_custom_23' AND CAST(StartF.meta_value AS DATETIME) <= CURDATE())
  AND
  (EndF.meta_key = '_ecp_custom_27' AND CAST(EndF.meta_value AS DATETIME) >= CURDATE())
  AND
  (ImgURL.post_type = 'attachment')
  AND
  (Posts.ID IN (SELECT relationships.object_id FROM `wp_terms` AS terms
     INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` AS taxonomy ON terms.term_id = taxonomy.term_id
     INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` AS relationships ON taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = relationships.term_taxonomy_id
     WHERE terms.name = 'Sydney'))

LIMIT 300
GROUP BY Title;";
```

Not sure why it doesn't like the Group By bit. Thanks.

Comment: **limit** comes last

Comment: `group by` first then `limit`

Comment: @dev odedra your edit broke the question, i rolled it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIMIT 300` This should come at the end of the query.

```
GROUP BY Title LIMIT 300
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT  Posts.post_title AS Title, ImgURL.guid AS Imgguid, Posts.guid, Posts.post_content
FROM `wp_posts` AS Posts
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS Meta ON Posts.ID = Meta.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS Featured ON Posts.ID = Featured.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS StartF ON Posts.ID = StartF.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS EndF ON Posts.ID = EndF.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS ImgID ON Posts.ID = ImgID.post_id
  INNER JOIN `wp_posts` AS ImgURL ON ImgID.meta_value = ImgURL.ID
WHERE
  (Featured.meta_key = '_ecp_custom_22' AND Featured.meta_value = 'yes')
  AND
  (StartF.meta_key = '_ecp_custom_23' AND CAST(StartF.meta_value AS DATETIME) <= CURDATE())
  AND
  (EndF.meta_key = '_ecp_custom_27' AND CAST(EndF.meta_value AS DATETIME) >= CURDATE())
  AND
  (ImgURL.post_type = 'attachment')
  AND
  (Posts.ID IN (SELECT relationships.object_id FROM `wp_terms` AS terms
     INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` AS taxonomy ON terms.term_id = taxonomy.term_id
     INNER JOIN `wp_term_relationships` AS relationships ON taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = relationships.term_taxonomy_id
     WHERE terms.name = 'Sydney'))
GROUP BY Title
LIMIT 300
```

Comment: a, formatting. b, the OP already said it was sorted. c, dont just dump code explain it